# How do we upload to Cloudflare images Direct Creator Upload URL using FilePond?

Tags: cloudflare, filepond

Uploading to Cloudflare Images with FilePond fails returning a 400. I'm testing it side by side with a simple form. I get the Direct Creator Upload URL from our api, pass it in to both components. The form always succeeds, while FilePond always fails. Can anyone suggest a fix please?
https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/cloudflare-images/upload-images/direct-creator-upload/

It's returning a 400 Bad Request. Can someone from CloudFlare or from FilePond figure out why CF Images is responding that the request from FilePond is malformed?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from "react-filepond";

import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type";
import DefaultButton from "./BaseComponents/defaultButton";

// Register the plugins
registerPlugin(
  FilePondPluginImagePreview,
  FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
);

interface Props {
  uploadURL: string;
}

export default function UploadAvatar(props: Props) {
  const { uploadURL } = props;
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<any>([]);
  return (
    <>
      {/* This simple form uploads successfully */}
      <form action={uploadURL} method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="myFile" name="file" />
        <DefaultButton type="submit">Upload Image</DefaultButton>
      </form>

      {/* FilePond upload fails with a 400 */}
      <div className="h-44 w-44 rounded-full ring-4 ring-light-control-accent-rest dark:ring-dark-control-accent-rest">
        <FilePond
          files={files}
          onupdatefiles={setFiles}
          allowMultiple={false}
          maxFiles={1}
          server={uploadURL}
          name="file"
          labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
          acceptedFileTypes={["image/*"]}
          onerror={(error) => console.log(error)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay so the solution to this is to take control of the file processing to ensure we are only sending the file.

Use the method outlined here: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#process-1 replacing `url-to-api` with the Direct Creator Upload url we get from Cloudflare's API. If you are using TS note that as of today there is a type mismatch which causes an error. Just remove `transfer options` from the function params to fix.

More details here: https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/818